# Add recursive defenses to the quality standards

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, question-quality, quality-filter

Or in less complex words: **ignore the string `It does not meet our quality standards` when checking if something meets our quality standards**. There are incidents across the network of users who simply repeat the error message when they fail the quality standards, and somehow that is enough to allow them to post. It's ridiculous, to paraphrase Mrozek, that such noise is permitted to slide through so brazenly.

At this time, a search for this string on Stack Overflow yields 14 live results and 11 dead results, none of which use the phrase for anything other than whining about hitting the quality standards. Even so, I'm suggesting that the phrase simply be *ignored*, not inflict a penalty. That way, if someone, somehow, has a legitimate question that happens to contain that phrase, then it won't get blocked (like those problems with `problem` in the title). But by ignoring the phrase, it will keep poor quality posts from getting through. No matter how many times they copy-paste the phrase (another common method of trying to work around it).

Comment: The fact the same sentence is repeated consecutively should be a sign of low quality post.

Comment: No, the [self-reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-reference) is a sign of _high_ quality!

Comment: Examples: [One](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127521/remove-colorfilter-undo-setcolorfilter), [Two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7479307/how-can-i-detect-shift-key-down-in-javascript), [Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181637/is-intellisense-possible-with-the-appmobi-xdk), [Four](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413901/how-to-set-parameters-in-liblinear), [Five](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631590/creating-a-customview)

Comment: Related: [Add attempts to game the "quality standards" filter to the Low Quality queue for review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/181332/289691)

Answer (score 8):

The big problem is not that one can circumvent the test by adding the error message to the question, but that this has become common and almost acceptable behavior. An easy fix is to ignore that string, but it could be replaced by any other string that tricks the control.

As seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413901/how-to-set-parameters-in-liblinear) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181637/is-intellisense-possible-with-the-appmobi-xdk) question (provided by NullUserException), the original question was not all that bad, but the reaction the user had to the error message was to lessen the quality rather then to fix it. How about giving some other alternative that might be more attractive then to copy paste in the error message, like showing some typos that can be fixed or probable code that can be formatted. Fixing any of these should suggest that the question has at least been revised once and that the asker has put some thought into it.