# Add attempts to game the "quality standards" filter to the Low Quality queue for review

Tags: feature-request, review, low-quality-posts, quality-filter

People who are not capable of writing high quality questions are nonetheless capable of figuring out how to get past the quality filter. By and large they add a sentence whining about the quality standards. These are [easy to search for](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22quality%20standards%22%20is:question) and I've included a selection at the end of this question. I think the last one is my favourite.

I would like to see the quality filter react to this somehow. I understand some real questions contain the magic words *quality standards* so **I wouldn't want these rejected**, but can they **go straight to the VLQ queue**, regardless of the poster's rep or the post's "quality score" or vote history? We have a VLQ queue just ready and waiting and usually empty. Humans will deal with these things promptly and mercilessly, I expect. Reviewers can edit out the filler to leave a legitimately short question, or can fix the (typically very many) other issues in the post, or flag it or whatever. If it's actually about quality standards, they can click <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> or even vote it up. Turning the quality filter up higher would making searching for these impossible - see pr0blem - but letting these through and adding them to the VLQ queue would, imo, benefit the site.

And now, some of the "improvements" to post quality that I edited out this morning:

---

Friends,

Sorry for drawing this out, I'm having trouble getting through SO's quality standards and think adding a little more text might let it through.

---

and this SO quality standards does more bad than good because I have multiple times had to put some  bit of useless crap info in my post just to get around it. thanks.

---

Why do I have to write a book in order to meet the quality standards and get the question posted? I have asked my question, then stated what works, and what I've tried. What more is required in a question?

---

i'm sorry but i have to repeat this code becuz apparently my question is too short and doesn't meets stackoverflow quality standards

```
$('.radio').change(function(){
  alert($(this).html()); // this is the selected
  alert($(old).html()); // this is the selected
})

$('.radio').change(function(){
  alert($(this).html()); // this is the selected
  alert($(old).html()); // this is the selected
})
```

---

Please help me out and can you pro's keep it as simple as possible, i know you have these ways but something pretty basic that i can understand. Thanks!!

```
Not real code
Won't let me meet quality standards
```

Comment: Nice try, Kate.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn eh?

Comment: I think he's referring to your multiple, extremely obvious attempts to bypass the quality standards filter to post your question.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist oh man. Time for more coffee. Good one, Bolt - I actually lol'ed.

Comment: what type of question are people going to be asking if the cannot meet the quality standards for length... SO is not a chat window `HRU, SUP, ASL` etc. Any question that is constructed of one or two sentences should really just get downvoted and deleted and we should not waste our time trying to help people who didnt make any effort in the first place

Comment: @mehow I agree. I don't come at this from wanting to help them. They are getting their crappy two sentence questions onto the site by adding a few more sentences that whine about the filter, or some fake code like the last guy, or code they already added but add 2 more times like the second last guy. I want our queues to pick these up so that we can edit or flag or close them. As it stands now, the questions get through to the site and may go undetected.

Comment: Cause the phrase "quality standards" to trigger the quality filter. Then, cause repeating text to trigger the quality filter. Then people will actually have to be creative.

Comment: At some point instead of preventing the post from being posted (see pr0blem etc) I would rather let it through and put it in a queue. We have a VLQ queue just ready and waiting and usually empty. Humans will deal with these things promptly and mercilessly, I expect.

Comment: @KnightswhosayNi Unfortunately even then I think a lot of them are still going to spend the time working out how to bypass the filter rather than spend the time learning how to write a decent question.

Comment: @KateGregory most of the time those questions are down voted and flagged by other users within minutes

Comment: @mehow I disagree. Take a look at my recent edits. http://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory?tab=activity A number of those questions have a positive score and all are still open. Those are the questions I drew the above examples from.

Comment: and this happens once in every 1K questions maybe

Comment: @mehow SO gets 10 q/min - so 1/1000 means a dozen or more of these "false passes" a day, every day, forever, and depending on the tags not getting handled by our current mechanisms

Comment: its only an estimate. even a dozen of them per day should not make it a huge deal. I like the idea of improving the quality standards brain, although i think there are more important issues to worry about when it comes to people by-passing restrictions

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't the existing system of close votes and delete votes already suffice?

Addressing some of the issues raised in the comments:

- A substantial percentage of very short questions are perfectly fine questions that should stay on the site.  It doesn't always have to be an essay.
- How many variants of qu@lity st@ndards are you going to check for?  We have a long and colorful history of pr0blems with stop words like these.
- Determined users will always find a way around the filter.
- I can live with a dozen such questions per day.  We already have the quality filter cranked up so high that some people do get frustrated with it, and there is the occasional false positive.

The appropriate action: Downvote with a vengeance, and politely explain that yes, we really do want actual quality in your questions.  The example comments and edits you provided are entirely appropriate.

---

When the quality filters and question bans were first put into place, they were very controversial.  SE didn't consult the community before creating them, and they were widely regarded as draconian and unfair.  Today, we recognize how valuable they are, and look for ways to add more automation. :)

That's not necessarily a bad thing, but the purpose of those filters is not to catch *everything,* it is to catch a large percentage of crap, and leave the small amount of remaining crap for the community to sweep up.  *To do otherwise is to engage in an arms race with a tiny minority of the user community, which is something we should not be doing.*

10 questions per day where people blatantly game the filter, only to be quickly edited, downvoted or closed by the community, seems like [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) to me.

Comment: I don't want the filter to reject questions that include the phrase. I want the questions to go to the VLQ queue where humans can edit out the filler to leave a legitimately short question, or can fix the (typically very many) other issues in the post, or flag it or whatever. If it's actually about quality standards, they can click No Action Needed. Turning the quality filter up higher would making searching for these impossible - see pr0blem - but letting these through and adding them to the VLQ queue would, imo, benefit the site.

Comment: But one close vote already throws it into the close queue.  Granted, there's a lot of things in that queue right now, but looking at the queue, the newest questions appear to be surfaced first.  There's also the "First Posts" queue.  Review Queues are meant to provide additional visibility for a question; are these questions being ignored?

Comment: The last edit I did was for a question 11 months old, the user has about 800 rep. I don't think that question ever spent time in First Posts. That's why I want the phrase detection to put the question in VLQ even if the poster has some rep, or has asked many questions before. At a minimum, these people are teaching each other how to get past the filter.

Comment: That's a fair point.