# User adds nonsense content to a question to get it through content filter; correct workflow?

Tags: discussion, quality-filter

I just reviewed a suggested edit to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19273526/revisions) in which the original author had included nonsense content to a question to get it through content filter and then another user had (helpfully) removed it. I approved the edit, but I'm at a loss what else to do.

The end result of this seems to have been to completely defeat the content filter, what should I do (if anything) now? The post is clearly not great (after all it failed the filter) but I'm not sure I could flag it for any of the close reasons in good faith, equally I can only make cosmetic improvements to it by edit.

Comment: I hope you haven't downvoted a question due to bad edit? It punishes OP (who can edit without review) and not the editor who misbehaved...

Comment: No no, I downvoted because the edit was nessissary, the editor **removed** the nonsense

Comment: Oh, OK, sorry, seems I misunderstood you. I'm not a native speaker and sometimes English tricks me that way.

Comment: It wasn't 100% clear, I've hopefully clarified

Comment: Now my big question is - what filter would be triggered if there was no random text in the post? That should hint about correct workflow for such cases.

Comment: remove none-sense. flag to close if its off-topic. if you come across the question and see it's been edited then retract your vote and remove your downvote(if youve placed one).

Comment: @mehow But that suggests we're prepared for people to defeat the filter like this, (I can only presume) the question in its current form would trigger the filter; its not off topic as such, its just not very good (so not good as to fail the filter)

Comment: So let me clarify this - if the post hadn't had the nonsense it wouldn't have been able to be posted, but by adding the nonsense *and then removing it* the post was then able to exist? That does seem a bit wrong.

Comment: @JonW It does, but I don't see any way around it. I don't think we want to prevent editors from removing nonsense...

Comment: @Mansfield Agreed, the question is unarguably better post edit. Possibly an auto flag if an edit pushed a question back into failing the filter?

Comment: related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181332/add-attempts-to-game-the-quality-standards-filter-to-the-low-quality-queue-for

Comment: If you wish to cast a moderator flag, just explain the situation in a custom flag, like you did here.  I wouldn't bother approving suggested edits that help someone work around a quality filter.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks, that will be my next step in future, given that you're already aware of it I shalln't in this case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, we try to discourage actions that will help someone get around a system limitation, so I would decline the suggested edit.

Regularly trying to subvert the quality filters is a suspendable offense.  If it has become a problem, flag one of the OP's posts for moderator attention using a custom flag, and explain the situation.